# no suitable method found for add(int,T) with Generics

Tags: java, sorting, tree, queue

I wrote my own PriorityQueue class to manage unlimited elements. TO do this I declared an ArrayList and then I used the standard methods to add/swap the elements in it, but I get the error in the title. This is my code:

```
public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    private ArrayList<E> queue;

    public PriorityQueue() {
        queue= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public <T> int size() {
        return queue.size();
    }

    public <T> boolean isEmpty() {
    return queue.isEmpty();
   }

    public <T> void insert(E element) {
        queue.add(queue.size(), element);
        siftUp(queue.size()-1);
    }

    public <T> void siftUp(int size) {
        E elem = queue.get(size);
        for (; size>0 && elem.compareTo(queue.get(size/2))==1; size=size/2)
            queue.add(size, queue.get(size/2));
        queue.add(size, elem);
    }
}
```

How do I can solve it?
Edit: changed from "T elem" to "E elem" and now it compiles, but inserts two identical elements.

Comment: `insert` should be declared as `insert(E element)` and what is `T` doing here?

Comment: What is the parameter `T` anyway?

Comment: Is a generic element declared by the user. It can be an int, a string ecc...

Comment: Well, you have a list of Apples, and you try adding Oranges to it. If you declare the queue to be based on the type `E`, all the methods should be based on that same `E`.

Comment: Remove the method-level `<T>` and use the class-level `E` instead. Aside from anything, it is unused in 3 of the 4 methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// perhaps this what you meant to do... Maybe? Kinda?
public class PriorityQueue<E> extends Comparable<E>
{
    private ArrayList<E> queue = new ArrayList<E>();

    public PriorityQueue() { }

    public int size()         { return queue.size(); }

    public boolean isEmpty()  { return queue.isEmpty(); }

    public void insert(E element) {
        queue.add(queue.size(), element);
        siftUp(queue.size() - 1);
    }


    public void siftUp(int size) {
        E elem = queue.get(size);
        for (; size>0 && elem.compareTo(queue.get(size/2))==1; size=size/2)
            queue.add(size, queue.get(size/2));
        queue.add(size, elem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh... I feel stupid ... In my defense, I use generics all day, but ... Actually ... I never declare or create my own... Sorry!

Comment: Almost 100% of the instantiated classes I use are from java.until.*   I don't write any "instiaible  objects" myself...   Mostly reuse Vector<>, Stack<>, TreeSet<>, TreeMap<>,  Hashrable<>. ...  (Thusly I've forgotten how <T> is actually used by the java compiler... But, indeed, after reviewing the link provided by @Radiodef ...  The question seems to be misusing <T> ...